# SQL Percentage of users falling in a specific range

Tags: mysql, query

I have a list of users with corresponding date of birth.
Is there any possibility I can get **a percentage** of users born between 1990 and 2000 in a **single SQL query**?

The query I tried is as follows:

```
Select (Select count(distinct user) as users from Visitors
  where birthyear between 1990 and 2000)/count(distinct user) from Visitors
```

But it gives me a zero as result.

Comment: Show us the `CREATE TABLE Visitors ...` statement and a sample of few rows. Are you sure you have both `user` and `users` as columns in this table?

Comment: Sorry there was a typing error...resolved. I imported the table from a cvs file.

Comment: can a single user show up more than once in the `Visitors` table?  if the answer is 'yes', what do you expect to happen if the user has 2 different values for `birthyear` ... one in the desired range and one outside of the desired range?

Comment: what datatype is `Visitors.birthyear`? have you verified there are users with `birthyear between 1990 and 2000`, ie, what does the following return: `Select count(distinct user) from Visitors where birthyear between 1990 and 2000`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 100.0 * SUM(birthyear between 1990 and 2000) /
               COUNT(*)  AS pct
    FROM ( SELECT userid, MAX(birthyear) AS birthyear
             FROM visitors GROUP BY userid ) AS x
```

Some notes:

- `SUM(boolean-expr)` is a way to count how often it is TRUE.
- `between 1990 and 2000` includes 101 distinct years because `BETWEEN` is 'inclusive'.  Are you sure you wanted that?
- `COUNT(*)` will count all the rows from the derived table (the subquery)
- `MAX` is a kludge -- A visitor might put down different birthyears on different visits.
- Whenever a subquery is used, it must have parentheses around it.
- The 'composite' index `INDEX(userid, birthyear)` would help performance some.